# What is the scenarios to use content vs schema keyword when describing parameters in OpenAPI specification

Tags: swagger, openapi

I couldn't completely understand the scenarios for using schema keyword over content keyword and vice versa while describing the parameters with OpenAPI specification. On reading through this https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/, i got an understanding that we should use schema keyword when describing any primitive or defined object params. It is mentioned that we should go for content keyword on complex scenarios, which is what i am not able to get. An explanation with an appropriate example for the scenarios would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

content is used in complex **serialization** scenarios.
For these complex types you need to wrap the parameter schema into content/media-type.
check [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/serialization/)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34633302)